# Error 400 bad request when creating a group calendar event in powershell with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an event in a calendar in an Office 365 group via powershell.

This is my first experience to do this type of programming so sorry if my question will be very basic :-)

First, I created a simple json file (calendar.json)

```
{
  "start":
{
 "dateTime":"2017-03-12T17:00:00.0000000",
 "timeZone":"UTC"
},
"end":
{
 "dateTime":"2017-03-12T17:30:00.0000000",
 "timeZone":"UTC"
},
  "responseStatus": {
    "response": "None"
  },
  "iCalUId": "null",
  "isReminderOn": false,
  "subject": "Test Event created from API"
}
```

Then I create the event with these steps:

Use a tested powershell function that give me the token
Add header with this code:

```
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('Authorization','Bearer ' + $token.AccessToken)
$headers.Add('Content-Type',"application/json")
```

Because I'm starting now, I convert the json file in an object and then the object in json (I know, it's quite stupid, but I've done so beacuse I have no knowledge of json and how convert without error in powershell code)

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject (Gc 'C:\Users\mmangiante\OneDrive - Interactive Media S.p.A\Office 365\calendar.json'-Raw)
$body = ConvertTo-Json $json
```

Call the Invoke-RestMethod

```
response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/768afb0c-bafd-4272-b855-6b317a3a9953/calendar/events' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $json
```

What is returned is a 400 bad request.

It's the same error of [Sending Microsoft Graph request events returns 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090956/sending-microsoft-graph-request-events-returns-400)

Given the answer given to that question I modified my code to return the error:

```
try{$restp=Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/768afb0c-bafd-4272-b855-6b317a3a9953/calendar/events' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $json
} catch {$err=$_}
$err
```

like suggested in [How do I get the body of a web request that returned 400 Bad Request from Invoke-RestMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986647/how-do-i-get-the-body-of-a-web-request-that-returned-400-bad-request-from-invoke) but I found nothing of interest.
The only thing that I found is that, at the time of writing, the Invoke-RestMethod doesn't return the full response as in this https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2193

I suppose my json is not "well formed", but I don't know why.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This formatting has worked for me in the past. Let me know if this resolves your issues:

```
$headers = @{ 
    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}

$body = @{
    Name1 = 'Value1';
    Name2 = 'Value2';
}

$bodyJSON = $body | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri <API HERE> -Headers $headers -Body $bodyJSON -OutFile $output
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shawn,

I tried your suggestion but without luck; I have done other test with 2 other api and found discordant results.
The first test is to use the graph api related to contact, creating a contact as in https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_contacts

I created the powershell representation of the sample json:

```
$contactbody = @{
    givenName = 'Ciccio';
    surname = 'Patacca';
    emailAddresses = @(
        @{
            address = 'cicciopatacca@cicciociccio.com'
            name = 'Ciccio Patacca'
        }
    )
    businessPhones = (
        '+39 555 123 4567'
    )
}
```

and then converted in json

```
$contactbody = $contactbody | ConvertTo-Json
```

I retrieved from Azure Portal the object ID related to my user in my company and so I call the rest method:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/e37d2dbe-bdaf-4098-9bb0-03be8c653f7d/contact' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $contactbody
```

The final result is a 400 bad request error.
So, I tried another example and reused some code retrieved from a google search.
This time I copied the powershell json representation as in the sample and converted:

```
$body = @{"displayName"="ps-blog"; "mailEnabled"=$false; "groupTypes"=@("Unified"); "securityEnabled"=$false; "mailNickname"="ps1" } | ConvertTo-Json
```

and, as stated in https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups I called the rest method

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

and this worked.
So I thought that the previously powershell representations of the sample with the error were not correctly formed (even if when I printed it they are equal to the samples on the graph api); for test, I rewritten the last powershell of the body as this:

```
$body = @{
    displayName = 'TestGraphGroup';
    mailEnabled = $true;
    groupTypes = @('Unified')
    securityEnabled = $false;
    mailNickname = 'TestGraphGroup'
}

$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

and invoked last method: it worked again.

So, where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A new SDK was released that makes this easier.
Checkout instructions on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871056/how-can-i-use-microsoft-graph-net-sdk-in-powershell)