# How can i use Microsoft Graph .NET SDK in powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

How can i use Microsoft Graph .NET SDK in powershell? I am writing a powershell script to use Microsoft Graph SDK.

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: I want to convert following C# code to powershell: 
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider( async (requestMessage) => { requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer") }));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph has a [powershell SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell). The packages from this SDK are published to [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/0.9.1). It is published as a Meta package `Microsoft.Graph` which contains all the modules. However, you can install individual modules as you see fit as they are available.

You can install the module using the following command in a powershell console.
`Install-Module Microsoft.Graph`

You can install single modules such as the Users or Teams modules

- `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Teams.Team`
- `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Users.User`

To authenticate call `Connect-Graph` which uses Device Code Flow or Certificate to Authenticate. You can also pass in your desired scopes.

- `Connect-Graph`
- `Connect-Graph -Scopes 'User.Read'`

From that point you gain access to cmdlets such as `Get-MgUser`

Answer (score 0):

Basically in order to access this API you first need to be authenticated with ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library), this authentication will is done trough a JSON formatted token that is then passed as a parameter in the header for the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet.

See how simple it is, take a look at these references:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2016/03/21/working-with-azure-active-directory-graph-api-from-powershell/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2017/09/05/using-powershell-to-connect-to-microsoft-graph-api/

Comment: I know how to invoke a rest api from powershell. I just want to convert following C# code to powershell

Comment: GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer")
                    }));